# With two point sets A and B, what is an efficient way of finding points in B that are not in A

Tags: algorithm, set, quadtree, difference

I have a pointset representing a set of polygons which I pass to a polygon boolop (clipping) algorithm. Once I get the result, I want to know what points the boolop newly created -- these would be due to intersection of polygon edges. So if A is the pointset before the operation and B is the pointset after the operation, I want to know which points are in B but not in A.

Should I use an ordinary set type (like C++ std::set) with an appropriate comparison defined and then do a difference, or would it be best to implement a quadtree and then do a difference? Do such opensource quadtree implementations exist which provide differencing? I googled for quadtree but most seem to relate to nearest-neighbour problems which are not relevant for my requirements.

I would be having a maximum of 1000 points per operation.

Thank you!

Comment: Are the polygon convex? It would make things much much easier.

Comment: Next question: are the polygon [complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_polygon) as in "does it intersect itself?"

Comment: If it is not convex, but not complex either. Then I think you can get some idea from [polygon flood-fill](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_fill/) algorithm. It usually need to build a data structure that keeps track of which area is filled.

Comment: Why can't you clip the polygon yourself?

Comment: @Billiska: The polygons are convex but they will intersect themselves.

Comment: @David: I can't clip the polygons myself because I don't understand the algorithms and would prefer to avoid putting in the effort to learn (though I might have to if no other go).

Comment: @jamadagni but [convex polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons) does not intersect themselves by definition. Did you misunderstand something?

Comment: @Billiska: Thanks for that clarification. Having read the Wikipedia article and thought some, I agree my polygons are not convex. Sorry about that. But really, this is about finding points in B that are not in A. While I agree that if I implemented the boolop myself I could customize things better, and I am in fact thinking of just forking or patching the opensource clipping library I chose, but for now I would like to know about how best to do difference of 2D point sets, just to keep my options open.

Comment: Aside update: It seems the library itself may start to get some functionality for bezier clipping (which is why I wanted to know the newly produced points in the first place): http://sourceforge.net/p/polyclipping/discussion/1148419/thread/cae35ac2/. So while the question about doing diff of 2D point sets still stands, it might become academic rather than practical for me now...